# I have a properties file at location (from eclipse mars project explorer)

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, properties-file

I have a properties file at location (from eclipse mars project explorer):

```
-MyTest(EJB PROJECT)
+EJBMODULE
+Source Packages
-Resource
    +Config.properties     <---- Here it is

    .....
    ....
```

Now when I am trying to find this file using code

```
prop = new Properties();
try {
       prop.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Its throwing java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: did you define `Resource` being a *source folder* in the projects *build path* preferences?

Comment: ya resolved ....Thanks -Timothy

Comment: I made an answer from the comment...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that of all platforms only the Windows operating system is case-insensitive. In a jar/ear/war all paths are case sensitive:

```
prop.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Config.properties"));
```

Do you c the C?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> prop.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"));
> ```

This construct looks for the resource within the applications *ClassPath*.

If you separate your resources from the `*.java` files in your project you have to configure your *IDE* so that the *root folder* of your resources is added to the applications *ClassPath* at runtime (especially in eclipse that means that the content of `ProjectRoot/Resource` will be copied to `ProjectRoot/bin` along with the `*.class` files).

however

I'd suggest to follow the [maven standard project directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and convert you Project to a *maven* or *greadle* project so that the class path is set up automatically.